# Qusetion on [expr.mptr.oper]/4

Tags: c++, class, undefined-behavior

[[expr.mptr.oper]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mptr.oper#4.sentence-2) states that:

> [..] If the dynamic type of E1 does not contain the member to which E2
> refers, the behavior is undefined [..].

Does the following code is UB?

```
struct B { int a{ 10 };  };
struct D : B { int a{ 15 }; };

B b; 
b.*static_cast<int B::*>(&D::a); // Does [expr.mptr.oper]/4 applies?
```

The value returned from the member access expression is just random. why?

If I just replace the above code with the following, I get the value B::a `10`:

```
struct B { int a{ 10 };  };
struct D : B { int a{ 15 }; };

D d; 
std::cout << d.*static_cast<int D::*>(&B::a);
```

Why now the value `10` returned and not `15`? or why the problem is fixed (I think is fixed)?

Answer (score 1):

Member pointers are initialized by a name, but after that the name is irrelevant, and the offset is what matters.  Given the memory layout of the objects with inheritance, the derived class data begins *after* the base class ends.  Thus, applying a derived class member pointer into a base class may access out of bounds.  In your case, derived's `a` member is outside of the base, so trying to read at the derived::a offset in a base object is undefined behavior.

But casting a base to derived is safe (when dealing with member pointers) because the derived class inherits the same memory layout as its base, plus more.  So the base pointer "works" in the derived.

It's interesting that class pointers are co-variant, but *member pointers* are contra-variant.  That means the member pointers safe to downcast, but not safe to upcast -- the exact opposite of class pointers.

Comment: The layout doesn't really matter, although it explains where the garbage value comes from. What matters is that `static_cast<int B::*>(&D::a)` points to a member of `D` and `b` doesn't have that member, which then causes UB if `.*` is applied.

Comment: @user17732522 - No `b` does have that member with value `10` And if you remove that member from `D`, you get the value `10`

Comment: @0x0 Just because the name is the same doesn't make it the same member. `B::a` and `D::a` are two different members of `D`.

Comment: @0x0 This answer already explains from a point-of-view of the typical implementation what happens. It is just missing the formal reason for UB. If you remove the member `a` in `D`, then name lookup of `D::a` will find `B::a` and so you are referring to `B::a` all along.